# How to emphasize being complimented professionally?

Tags: adjectives, vocabulary

I would like to say something along the lines that *"I am honored to accept... (job, award, etc)"* but without using the term *honored* as I find it more dramatic sounding <sub>(purely my subjective sentiment only)</sub> than I would like for my professional context, as wouldn't, for example,*flattered* be very suitable either, for similar reasons.

What is a less emotional <sub>(now I know this is subjective)</sub> way to emphasize that you feel complimented by the circumstances from the context more suitable for professional communication?

Comment: "pleased" or "gratified" might work.

Answer (score 3):

[**Privileged**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/privileged) would be a good choice;

> 1.1 - *[with infinitive]* Having been granted a special honour.

I think this a good fit to keep the statement professional while not sounding too dramatic and still conveying a small level of emotion that the offer (of the job or award) conveys.